# Access the filer plugin directly to link pages with thumbnails

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-cms

I'm looking at creating a thumbnail based upon the first image which is placed on a page. I was thinking that the best way of doing this would be by accessing the filer plugin directly.

The documentation isn't clear on how I can do this. Does anybody know?

I know that I can access the Page Titles using:

```
from cms.models import Title

Title.objects.all()
```

Is there a similar method for accessing the images on each page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the filer image model like so:

```
from filer.models.imagemodels import Image

Image.objects.all()
```

Edit:
If you are trying to access the images that are in the placeholders and are in the view you may use the following to get the pages cmsplugin_filer instances. (This is untested but should hopefully help)

```
if request.current_page:
    placeholders = request.current_page.placeholders.all()
    plugins = []

    for placeholder in placeholders:
        plugins += list(placeholder.get_plugins().filter(plugin_type='PicturePlugin'))

    images = [p.image for p in plugins]
```

Comment: Spot on! Do you know of a way to validate when an image has been used on a specific page?

Comment: @Josh do you mean used in the pages placeholders? Or have you added a custom page extension model? I assume your using Django cms

Comment: I am indeed, but I'm very new to this. I apologise if what I'm asking doesn't make sense. I've added images through the CMS' filer plugin itself to individual pages. I'm making myself a blog and I'd like to be able to create a library of thumbnails which represents each blog post. Ideally the thumbnails should be generated automatically. The code that you've suggested accesses the filer, and I'm wondering if there's a way to find if they've been used on a page, or compare to images detailed on a page object for validation

Comment: @Josh so it sounds like your adding the images in the page placeholders is this correct? If so you would need to filter based on the related_name that the cms filter plugin uses in its model

Comment: I can’t test at the minute as I’m not on a computer but will be able to check tomorrow

Comment: Thanks, mate. I'm very grateful :) I'm adding through the CMS' default browser interface (i.e. not through the command line). I'm not completely au fait with the system architecture but it makes sense to me that it would be done through placeholders

Comment: @Josh most welcome :) placeholders are what Django cms use for the content of pages